# Why did Hopper smile when Admiral Shane said he will have chicken burrito?

Tags: plot-explanation, battleship

In [Battleship (2012)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1440129/), after the award ceremony.

Hopper went to Admiral Shane to take permission to marry his daughter (Sam), but he denied and said he will have "Chicken Burrito".

Hopper smirked, like "Chicken Burrito" was some hint. Hint that Admiral was joking.

What was it?

Comment: hint: how did the movie start

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The whole reason Alex Hopper is in the Navy is because he got drunk and broke into a closed convenience store to steal a Chicken Burrito to impress a girl.

[image]

Comment: Oh, I missed ... :)